# How do I handle extra top view when tethering, call

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

When we use tethering for use of 3G connectivity, the header appears twice as high. 
This means that the surface of my App being a little bit smaller.

[image]

How do I handle this in my application in a good way? 
Should I measure header bar everytime view appears ?  Or is that any delegate method for that ?

Best regards.
/ f0az

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement those methods from the UIApplicationDelegate:

```
– application:willChangeStatusBarFrame:
– application:didChangeStatusBarFrame:
```